# React StrictMode error with useEffect and setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have and useEffect inside my component

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setQueueState((pre) => {
        return pre.map((line) => {
          if (line.length === 0) return [];
          line[0].items = line[0].items > 0 ? line[0].items - 1 : 0;
          if (line[0].items > 0) {
            return [
              line[0],
              ...line.slice(1).filter((person) => person.items > 0)
            ];
          } else {
            return [...line.slice(1).filter((person) => person.items > 0)];
          }
        });
      });
    }, 4000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

What it basically does is to loop through an array of checkout lines and reduce the number of items of the first person in each line by 1. Now the problem with Strict Mode is that it gets reduced 2 times. I know it's because Strict Mode renders a component 2 times. I just want to know a way to avoid this and still use Strict Mode.

Comment: unrelated: this is not immutably updating state

Comment: lmao thank you i rewrote the hook so it does not mutate the state and now it works fine

Comment: But it's still valid question in general, see how here the result is 2: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tio6kx?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: I don't think your comment is unrelated. Mutating state is likely the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Wing See my above link to stackblitz

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: the cleanup in this case would be aborting the state change by queuing the reverse of the state change (`() => setA(ps => ps - 1)`).

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: cleanup and purity is especially important given concurrency features introduced in React 18 and beyond.

Comment: @Wing The cleanup function is often used to stop synchronizing the effect (e.g. stop listening to some event), I haven't seen it used to undo the actions performed in the effect as you suggest.

Comment: @Wing ps. "reversing the operation defined in the effect." what do you mean here? when would you do that? See also my comment above.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: this thread is getting long so I've asked and answered a question, see [How to fix React calling `setState` twice in `useEffect` that has an empty dependency array in strict mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76945781/how-to-fix-react-calling-setstate-twice-in-useeffect-that-has-an-empty-depen/76945782). This should answer both questions in your comments. Regarding "reversing the operation": in your example you incremented 1 so the reverse is to decrement; this is done in the cleanup function. Please comment on the other question as it's off-topic for this one.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, there are 2 renders with Strict mode on development. On my project, I create a hook called `useEffectOnce`.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export const useEffectOnce = (effect: React.EffectCallback) => {
  const mounted = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mounted.current) {
      return
    }
    mounted.current = true
    return effect()
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
useEffectOnce(() => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Why would you work around the protections offered by strict mode? If you do this you might as well disable strict mode in the first place. The best solution, however, is to ensure components are pure and effects are cleaned up.

Comment: @Wing Yeah but here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tio6kx?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter, there is no cleanup, component is also pure but result is 2. Just showing that there are sometimes cases when you might get undesired effect maybe ...?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: That's not OP's situation, though. While the answer proposed here may work and may be suitable for certain situations, it is not good practice for OP's situation. This answer would've hidden the impurity of OP's original code and increased the risk of bugs. However, I think in general, I still think this is a bad idea. Ultimately, I think it comes down to a mindset shift to thinking about how React works.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: From React's [documentation](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development): "React intentionally remounts your components in development to find bugs [...]. **The right question isn’t “how to run an Effect once”, but “how to fix my Effect so that it works after remounting.** [...] Usually, the answer is to implement the cleanup function. The cleanup function should stop or undo whatever the Effect was doing."

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: I've responded to your StackBlitz problem in the thread underneath the question. Kevin: you may be interested too given the conversation in this thread on your answer.

Comment: @Wing No one here is saying we should hack our way around React. The question specifically asked how to avoid having 2 renders in development mode without disabling Strict mode.

Comment: @KevinGilbert: the solution you're proposing here is the hack. See the quote from React's documentation in my previous comment. The root cause was due to impure state mutation. As mentioned in a previous comment, this solution would've hidden that problem instead of actually solving it. Regarding the more generic problem proposed in the StackBlitz, I've elaborated more on it in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76945781/how-to-fix-react-calling-setstate-twice-in-useeffect-that-has-an-empty-depen/76945782).

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the coment from Giorgi Moniava i rewrote the hook so it does not mutate the state and now it works as i wanted this is how the hook looks now

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setQueueState((prevState) => {
        const newQueueState = prevState.map((line) => {
          if (line.length === 0) return [];
          const firstPerson = {
            ...line[0],
            items: Math.max(0, line[0].items - 1)
          };
          const filteredLine = line
            .slice(1)
            .filter((person) => person.items > 0);

          if (firstPerson.items > 0) {
            return [firstPerson, ...filteredLine];
          } else {
            return filteredLine;
          }
        });

        return newQueueState;
      });
    }, 4000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: see my comment to your question, that might not always "save" you

Comment: will keep in mind for the future now im geting why everyone hates useEffect

Comment: Look at this: https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development, though I don't think this case (like in stackblitz) is mentioned there.