# How to fix React calling `setState` twice in `useEffect` that has an empty dependency array in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-strictmode

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;

function Test() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><Test /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Consider the above snippet proposing a hypothetical situation. The `Test` component has a `useEffect` which increments the count by `1`. The `useEffect` has an empty dependency array which means it should only get called on mount. Therefore, the count should be `1`. However, the count is `2`, when the  strict mode is enabled.

This question is drawn from a comment thread that started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76941083/react-strictmode-error-with-useeffect-and-setinterval?noredirect=1#comment135636814_76941083).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What is strict mode doing?

In React, strict mode will run effects twice. From [React's documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) (emphasis mine):

> Strict Mode enables the following development-only behaviors:
>
> - Your components will [re-render an extra time](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development) to find bugs caused by impure rendering.
> - **Your components will [re-run Effects an extra time](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development) to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup**.
> - Your components will [be checked for usage of deprecated APIs](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-deprecation-warnings-enabled-by-strict-mode).

## Cleaning up state?

The documentation says it's to find bugs caused by missing effect cleanup so you might be thinking the following. *What is there to clean up in this effect? The effect isn't controlling a non-React widget <sub>([example Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885346/re-rendering-with-react-strict-mode-and-fabrics-canvas-instantiation/76885535#76885535))</sub> nor subscribing to an event <sub>([example Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71103060/why-is-the-event-handler-called-twice))</sub>; it's just updating some state, there's nothing to clean up.*

However, there is clean up that can be done. The clean up is undoing the operation performed in the effect. The `useEffect` would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  
  return () => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1);
}, []);
```

The full working example:

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;

function Test() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    
     return () => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><Test /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

If you're thinking this is strange, I'd say:

- This is a hypothetical example. I can't think of an actual use case for setting state on mount (without doing anything else before, which may require a different way of cleaning up). If you do encounter something like this in a non-hypothetical situation, there may be smells of "[you might not need an effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)". Although, I haven't thought super hard so let me know if there's an actual use case you've thought of (it may also be worth it's own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)).
- React's [documentation](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development) supports this (emphasis mine):

  > Usually, the answer is to implement the cleanup function.  The cleanup function should stop or **undo whatever the Effect was doing**.
- There's also a similar example regarding *state* outside of React. See the example for handling `useEffect` firing twice when [triggering animations](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#triggering-animations). Code excerpt below:

  > ```
  > useEffect(() => {
  >   const node = ref.current;
  >   node.style.opacity = 1; // Trigger the animation
  >   return () => {
  >     node.style.opacity = 0; // Reset to the initial value
  >   };
  > }, []);
  > ```
- You need to understand why cleaning up, even state, is important. Onto this next.

When we think of React unmounting a component it's easy to think React just throws away the component and everything that comes with it (like state). However, this is not true. React might unmount a component then remount it with restored state. This might happen in cases like:

- Development fast refresh: making changes to components without losing state. You change a component and save a file, React unmounts the *old* component and remounts the *new* one and restores state from before the unmount.
- Offscreen components (upcoming API as part of React's concurrent features): a component is unmounted when it goes off the screen then remounted without losing state. This is useful in cases like:

  - Fluid navigation between screens (or tabs) in an app. You'd want to restore state when navigating back (or prerender when navigating forward).
  - Making long lists more performant. Items off the screen may be unmounted (or also prerendered) and remounted when they come back on.

If cleanup isn't performed you'll encounter bugs like the one in the question.

### A practical test with fast refresh

You can reproduce this yourself relatively easily by doing the following:

1. Start a new Create React App project. This has fast refresh enabled by default.
2. Setup the relevant files with the code in the question.
3. Start the app.
4. Make a change to the `Test` component and save it.

When you view the app, you'll see the component has updated with the change in step 4 however the count has also incremented. You can make multiple changes, saving each time and see the count continue to increment. This is because React unmounted the component then remounted it without losing state. The `setState` in the `useEffect` then operates on this restored state.

Now add in the cleanup described earlier and hard refresh the app to restore its initial state. You can perform step 4 again and see the count doesn't increment on every change.

## Further reading

- [What is Concurrent React?](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18#what-is-concurrent-react)
- [Adding Reusable State to StrictMode](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/19)
- [How to handle Effect firing twice in development?](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development)

Comment: In this case  you could reverse the + operation with -, but what if there was operation which has no reverse?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: do you have a more concrete example?

Comment: I don't know any operation in general which you can't undo easily. For example hash function instead of adding one.

Comment: If you can't undo the operation, the first things I would look at are: (1) Is aborting the operation or ignoring its results suitable (e.g. you can't undo a network request but you can ignore the response), (2) Does the thing you're doing need to be in an effect? If you really need an effect, I suppose the only solution left is to store the original state so you can use it in the cleanup function to reset to the original state.

Comment: Just trying to get the thinking behind this: So docs basically tell us to try to code our effect such that it is resilient to remounting? Even if I used `[]` as dependency and never intended this component to be mounted twice? That's why we have to put this additional code in cleanups?

Comment: Yes, effects should be written in a way that is resilient to remounting. An empty dependency array doesn't tell React not to run the effect on subsequent mounts, it only tells React not to run the effect on subsequent re-renders.

Comment: I worded poorly, I meant if I use [] and I know my component won't be mounted twice - docs still warn to assume it maybe mounted multiple times because of some upcoming features. But then those features should say when component remounts.

Comment: How do you guarantee your component won't be mounted twice?

Comment: Why not there can be some components sometimes when it doesn't make sense to render them at multiple places, so you just put it inside `App` without conditional rendering.

Comment: But the component isn't aware or responsible for determining if it only mounts once. As a result, it needs to be predictable in cases where it mounts more than once. If your effect is in the top most component, it could still be unmounted and remounted if fast refresh in development is enabled and a change in the top most component is made.